# Order images by date php following this code format

Tags: php

I have this code that gets all of the files in this directory, but I don't know how to modify it to order them by date. It currently shows all of the files and adds the pagination for it, but now the images aren't in date order, I've tried to do it using other stackoverflow answers, but it didn't work.

```
   <?php
    $maindir = "../source" ;
    $mydir = opendir($maindir) ;
    $limit = 20;
    $offset = ((int)$_GET['offset']) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0; 
    $files = array();
    $page='';
    $exclude = array( ".", "..", "index.php",".htaccess","guarantee.gif") ;
    while($fn = readdir($mydir))
    {
        if (!in_array($fn, $exclude)) 
        {                               
            $files[] = $fn;;
        }
    }
    closedir($mydir);
    $newICounter = (($offset + $limit) <= sizeof($files)) ? ($offset + $limit) : sizeof($files);

    for($i=$offset;$i<$newICounter;$i++) {  
    ?>
        <a href="<?php print $files[$i]; ?>"><?php print $files[$i]; ?></a><br>
    <?php
    }
    freddyShowNav($offset,$limit,sizeof($files),"");

    function freddyShowNav($offset, $limit, $totalnum, $query) {
        global $PHP_SELF;
        if ($totalnum > $limit) {
                // calculate number of pages needing links 
                $pages = intval($totalnum/$limit);

                // $pages now contains int of pages needed unless there is a remainder from division 
                if ($totalnum%$limit) $pages++;

                if (($offset + $limit) > $totalnum) {
                    $lastnum = $totalnum;
                    }
                else {
                    $lastnum = ($offset + $limit);
                    }
            echo $pages;
                ?>
                    <table cellpadding="4"><tr><td>Page </td>
                        <td>
                            <ul class="pager">
                                <li><a href="?offset=<?php echo $_GET['offset'] - 20; ?>"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Previous</a></li>
                                <li><a href="?offset=<?php echo $_GET['offset'] + 20; ?>">Next <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>

                        </tr></table>
                <?php
            }
        return;
        }
    echo $page;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Try use this 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php
with this http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php ?

To check file modify date can use filetime function like this

```
 while($fn = readdir($mydir))
{
    if (!in_array($fn, $exclude)) 
    {                               
        $files[] = array(
            'file_name' => $fn,
            'mod_time' => filemtime($maindir.'/'.$fn)
            );
    }
}
```

and sort table with files

```
usort($files, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['mod_time'] - $b['mod_time'];
});
```

Comment: Your answer will definitely help OP. But posting just some links without explaining how they work is a low quality post. If possible, please edit your answer and add a sample code which contains these two functions and show how do they work.

Comment: Where you have "filetime" isn't that supposed to be "filemtime"?
Also I didn't understand where I was supposed to put the usort thing... No matter what I type it just comes up with "Array" down the page.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, now is everry think should  be ok.

Comment: What do I echo out? `$files['file_name']` comes up blank... but `$files` came up with all of the images in arrays.

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [file_name] => DSC_0344.JPG [mod_time] => 1485913035 ) [1] => Array ( [file_name] => fCAvFcMU.png [mod_time] => 1488045479 ) ...` is how the images are shown right now.

Comment: It is very simple `<a href="<?php print $files[$i]['file_name']; ?>"><?php print $files[$i]['file_name']; ?></a><br>`, because you have multidimensional array

Comment: Thanks! Works now.